# How to change the rotation of the angle with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\node (x1)  at (0, 0, 0) {};
\node (x2)  at (2, 0, 0) {};
\node (x3)  at (3.45, 1.45, 0) {};
\node (x4)  at (4, 0, 0) {};
\shade [ball color=black] (x1) circle (0.15);
\shade [ball color=black] (x2) circle (0.15);
\shade [ball color=black] (x3) circle (0.15);
\shade [ball color=gray] (x4) circle (0.15);
\draw (x1) -- (x2) -- (x3);
\draw[gray] (x1) -- (x2) -- (x4);
\draw[gray,dashed] (4, 0, 0) arc (0:26:3cm);
\pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = x1--x2--x3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the following figure:

[image]

But I want the rotation of the angle arrow to be the opposite. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `\pic` makes angles anti-clockwise. Therefore, it should be `x3--x2--x1` instead of `x1--x2--x3`.

By the way, option `scale=1` is unnecessary.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x1)  at (0, 0, 0) {};
\node (x2)  at (2, 0, 0) {};
\node (x3)  at (3.45, 1.45, 0) {};
\node (x4)  at (4, 0, 0) {};
\shade [ball color=black] (x1) circle (0.15);
\shade [ball color=black] (x2) circle (0.15);
\shade [ball color=black] (x3) circle (0.15);
\shade [ball color=gray] (x4) circle (0.15);
\draw (x1) -- (x2) -- (x3);
\draw[gray] (x1) -- (x2) -- (x4);
\draw[gray,dashed] (4, 0, 0) arc (0:26:3cm);
\pic [draw, <-, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = x3--x2--x1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Edit 1

Better version IMHO

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x1)  at (0, 0, 0) {};
\node (x2)  at (2, 0, 0) {};
\node (x3)  at ({cos(26)*3+1}, {sin(26)*3}, 0) {};
\node (x4)  at (4, 0, 0) {};
\pic [draw, <-, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = x3--x2--x1};
\draw (x1) -- (x2) -- (x3);
\draw[gray] (x1) -- (x2) -- (x4);
\draw[gray,dashed] (4, 0, 0) arc (0:26:3cm);
\shade [ball color=black] (x1) circle (0.15);
\shade [ball color=black] (x2) circle (0.15);
\shade [ball color=black] (x3) circle (0.15);
\shade [ball color=gray] (x4) circle (0.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice :-). For my humble opinion the two gray horizontal segments should be in the background. So for the balls you don't see the dashes upstairs.

Comment: @Sebastiano Edited!